# Android SearchView Widget with Custom Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, listview, searchview, android-cursoradapter

Good Day,

I have implemented a custom cursor adpater to my listview. I also have a searchview widget associated with the listview. I am having issues implementing the search widget from the onCreateOptionsMenu and then perform a search. Here is what I have so far.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_flavors_actions, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    mCursor = mDbHelper.getflavorlist(null);
    final FlavorListAdapter adapter = new FlavorListAdapter(this, mCursor);
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return mDbHelper.getflavorlist(constraint.toString());
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Here is my cursor adapter

```
public class FlavorListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public FlavorListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

// The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
// you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.flavorlist, parent, false);
}

// The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
// such as setting the text on a TextView.
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // Find fields to populate in inflated template
    TextView nametext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView vendortext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vendor);
    TextView notestext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cnotes);
    // Extract properties from cursor
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
    String vendor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("vendor"));
    String notes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("notes"));
    // Populate fields with extracted properties
    nametext.setText(name);
    vendortext.setText(vendor);
    notestext.setText(notes);
}
}
```

And the database helper

```
 public Cursor getflavorlist (CharSequence constraint)  {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(
            DATABASE_TABLE2
    );

    String asColumnsToReturn[] = {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,VENDOR,BASE,BASEV,PERCT,NOTES,GRAVITY,INVENTORY};

    if (constraint == null  ||  constraint.length () == 0)  {
        //  Return the full list
        return queryBuilder.query(mDb, asColumnsToReturn, null, null,
                null, null, KEY_NAME);
    }  else  {
        String value = ""+constraint.toString()+"%";

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, asColumnsToReturn, "name like ?", new String[]{value}, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

I do not get any errors when the code runs. The search widget works but the list does not filter. What am I missing here?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide to Creating a Search Interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Comment: Well that's no help at all. That is exactly the source I used. Perhaps you did not understand the question. How do I use the search widget with a custom cursor adapter and filter the list?

Comment: Ok, you already know the text, that's good :) Which is your searchable activity? It will receive an Intent with the query (see "Receiving the query"), you have to check for the Intent in the searchable activity's onCreate(). Then you can query the database, update the data list and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(). I can't tell from the code you posted if you already know that as well, so let's assume you do. The next step would be the actual filtering: depending on the String extra, you run a database query, pass the result to the ListView adapter and finally call notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response. Where the hang up is, in the Custom Cursor Adapter. It is not an activity and so some of what the Developers Guide is stating will not work.